# Naming conventions for ERC-20 instancies

Tags: erc-20, conventions

Given a contract that implements ERC-20. Is there a naming convention for new instancies such as its symbol? We are used to 3 chars but that range will run out at some time in future.

I am asking because I suspect that market places and wallets for tokens cannot deal with long symbols.

Comment: Symbol lengths of up to 9(!) characters have been in use for a while now - see [Is there length limits on Token Symbols?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25619/is-there-length-limits-on-token-symbols)

Comment: Edit: In fairness, there are fewer 9-character symbols now than there were. It's probably safest to stay as close to 3 characters as possible... And I'm not confining this to ERC-20 tokens, but general assets that the exchanges would seem to be able to support.